# Galaxy S4 bluetooth voice commands

Tags: lock-screens, bluetooth, s-voice

Can anyone help me out. I recently changed my Razr for Galaxy S4 (SCH-I545) on Verizon. I would like to access S-Voice from my bluetooth headpiece, but if I have a pin number set for the phone's lock screen, the S-Voice app won't start when I push the bluetooth button until I unlock the screen. Sort of defeats the purpose of hands free use such as in the car. On the Droid Razr there was an option in the settings under security to allow bluetooth voice control with the phone locked, but I can't find this on the Galaxy. The hands free bluetooth access works if the lock screen pin is disabled, but I prefer to have the pin number set, especially if I'm out and about, and it's a pain to go into settings to disable the pin everytime I get in the car. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: What about looking into the settings menu in `S-voice --> settings --> headset mode` to see if anything might be unchecked?

Answer (score 0):

See if [Delayed Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.delayedlock2.trial) works for you. It's a 7-day trial app, with in-app purchase for license.

> Additionally, there is also an optional notification in the Android
>   status bar and a widget to immediately reenable the lock screen, and
>   **free plugins to automatically keep the device unlocked while connected to a specific WiFi network / Bluetooth device or at certain
>   locations.**

---

[Others](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=36199406&postcount=4) have used a combination of [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) and [Secure Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin) with this configuration:

Profile: State > Bluetooth Connected
`Task > Plugin > Secure Settings > Password/Pin > Disabled`

Exit Task:
`Task > Plugin > Secure Settings > Password/Pin > Enabled (Set to my old
PIN number)`